# Challenges with Compilation and Deploying to an arm32v7 Target Robot

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, cross-compilation

I'm encountering issues with compiling in my development environment and deploying the output to a target robot. I'd appreciate any guidance or insights you can offer.

**Setup:**

- **Development Environment:** A Docker container with full ROS2 Humble built with `docker buildx` to support `arm32v7` architecture for compilation.
- **Target Robot:** An `arm32v7`-based robot running ROS2 Humble, installed via Yocto.

**Workflow:**
I compile using `colcon build` in the Docker container.
I then transfer the `install` directory to the robot.
On the robot, I execute source `install/setup.bash` and run the nodes.
Issue:

A C++ node works perfectly.
However, I encounter errors with Python nodes or ROS2 commands (e.g., `ros2 topic echo /topic_name`). These nodes utilize custom ROS messages.

**Error Message:**

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py", line 48, in import_type_support
    raise UnsupportedTypeSupport(pkg_name)
rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport: Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'my_interfaces'
```

**Additional Context:**

- Post-compilation, there are `symlinks` in the build output pointing to local files. I've scripted a process to replace these with their target files.
- The primary concern seems to be with the `setup.bash` file in the `install` folder, which contains absolute paths, which are not present on the target robot. While commenting them out worked for the C++ package, it seems insufficient for Python/custom message scenarios.

```
# source chained prefixes
# setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids determining the prefix in the sourced script
COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="/home/root/ros2_humble/install"
_colcon_prefix_chain_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/local_setup.bash"
```

**Question:**
How should I properly compile and transfer the output from the development environment to the target robot?

Thank you